# How to access state / functions outside of react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement the strategy design pattern to dynamically change how I handle mouse events in a react component.

My component:

```
export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            grid: [],
            mouseLeftDown: false,
        };
        const mouseStrat2 = null;     // Object I will change that has different functions for handling events
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.resetGrid();
        this.mouseStrat2 = new StartEndStrat();
    }

    render() {
        //buttons that change the object i want handling mouse events
    <button onClick={() => this.mouseStrat2 = new StartEndStrat(this)}>startendstrat</button>
    <button onClick={() => this.mouseStrat2 = new WallStrat(this)}>wallstrat</button>
    }
}
```

I want my mouse strats that will access change the component with differing methods to handle mouse events

```
export class StartEndStrat {
    handleMouseDown(row, col) {
        // I want to access component state and call functions of the component
        this.setState({ mouseLeftDown: true });
        PathfindingVisualizer.resetGrid();
    }
    //other functions to change other stuff

    handleMouseEnter(row, col) {
        console.log('start end strat');
    }
}

export class WallStrat {
    handleMouseDown(row, col) {
        this.setState({ mouseLeftDown: true });
    }

    handleMouseEnter(row, col) {
        console.log('wallstrat');
    }
}
```

Comment: In React, a better idea would be to use a different wrapper component for each strategy. The child component would stay the same. The wrapper component would define the strategy, handle the state and maybe use a `ref` to the child component if needed (to hook events for example).

Comment: How would you change what function is called during an event then? I'm doing it this way because I want to avoid big if/switch statements. Assuming I have many different functions I want to implement.

Comment: You should have a look at this: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up and maybe this https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Comment: To change the functions called during events, you'd only need to change the wrapper component. And pass the child component as a prop to the wrapper component. `function WallStratWrapper({ children })`

Comment: Sorry for the bunch of docs, but what you want can be achieved as a HOC too: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I found was to use a ref callback to make the DOM element a global variable.

`<MyComponent ref={(MyComponent) => window.MyComponent = MyComponent})/>`

Then you can access MyComponent with `window.MyComponent`, functions with `window.MyComponent.method()` or state variables with `window.MyComponent.state.MyVar`

My App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PathfindingVisualizer ref={(PathfindingVisualizer) => {window.PathfindingVisualizer = PathfindingVisualizer}} />
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Other.js:

```
handleMouseDown() {
    window.PathfindingVisualizer.setState({mouseLeftDown: true});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [Refs](https://pl.reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to do this.

`refOfComponent.setState({ ... })`

But I would rather recommend you to avoid such constructions as this may add complexity to your codebase.